# Actionlink with confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, confirmation

I want to make a confirmation message appear before the link opens.  However, despite this, the link is followed despite clicking on cancel or closing the dialog.  Please help me, as I am stuck with this.

```
<div style="float: left; width: 40px; height: 10px; "> @Html.ActionLink("-Pg", "SupprimerPage", "Section", new { pageId = @item.Id }, new { onclick = "ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event);", @class = "editLink", style = "width:30px" })</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function ConfirmerSuppressionPage(event) {
    var x = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");
    console.log(x);
    if (x == null) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    if (x == true) {

        return true;
    }
    else {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Comment: Suggest you get rid of the `onclick` and just use `$('.editLink).click(function() { return confirm("Êtes-vous ....?"); })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke:  This still follows the URL despite clicking on Cancel.

Comment: @tabby what browser are you testing? In chrome and IE 11 all works as expected.

Comment: Works fine for me (both your code and mine). And with your code, all you need is one line of code - `return confirm("Êtes-vous....?");`

Comment: @teovankot:  I have tested on Chrome, IE and firefox.

Comment: @StephenMuecke:  I tested it on a fiddle and it works fine, but not in my project.  Any idea where I should look for this?  Please help, thanks

Comment: Any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @StephenMuecke:  There is no error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help, but I have had a similar problem of certain browsers not respecting the cancel button, and created a replacement function to solve it:

```
function showConfirm(str) {
    if (confirm(str) == false) {
        if (typeof (event) != "undefined") {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }

        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then in your `ConfirmerSuppressionPage` function, replace the call to `confirm` with `showConfirm`

Answer (score -1):

```
var result = confirm("Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette page?");
if (result == true) {
    x = "You pressed OK!";
} else {
    x = "You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`Confirm` is a JavaScript dialog box and it will return `true` or `false`. And JavaScript will not execute next line until user will not click on `Yes` or `No` button of dialog.

```
Any how Confirm will return you True or False, and now you have to deal with it.
```

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. OP is checking the return value.